# Pandas 0.19.2 read_excel IndexError: List index out of range

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am looking to parse an excel spreadsheet. I decided to use pandas but got caught by an error straight off the bat.

[image]

I started with the code below but played around with using a full path and also tried setting the sheetname.

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_excel('ss_12.xlsx')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

The excel spreadsheet is in the same directory as my script file. I taught it would work the same as open() in this sense, just a name required if its in the same directory. I have looked at a few examples online and going by them this should work.

[image]

I am trying to strip the first column seen in the image above. The full error (not sure how to format it, sorry)

```
C:\xx\Playpen\ConfigList_V1_0.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xx\Playpen\getConVars.py", line 12, in <module>
    pd.read_excel(excelFile)
  File "C:\xx\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 200, in read_excel
    **kwds)
  File "C:\xx\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 432, in _parse_excel
    sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(asheetname)
  File "C:\xx\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 432, in sheet_by_index
    return self._sheet_list[sheetx] or self.get_sheet(sheetx)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you post the full code you're using and the full error traceback? The image above is incomplete and I have no real idea what the problem is.

Comment: @noah this, I am afraid is the full code. I just started playing with it and this error happened with basic test attempts. Basically I tried loading my excel spread sheet. I put it in the same folder as the script and tried what you see above. I also tried using a full path e.g. pd.read_excel("C:\\....\\my_spread_sheet") and then i tried a named sheet e.g. pd.read_excel("C:\\....\\my_spread_sheet", sheetname='sheet1.xlsx')

Comment: Can you share the excel document? This seems like it might be a bug in pandas or the excel library, xlrd, that it's using. You might try submitting a bug report on the pandas github including an excel doc that causes the error.

Comment: @noah, I would rather not share the full document as its work related. I will look at sending a bug report and possibly share it through that medium.For now,  I think I will use a different module other than pandas. Thanks for the help

Comment: openpyxl also had a problem with the same document. Copied the contents to new document and i cna now open it up. I will add more information today. The error return from openpyxl seems more informative.

Comment: I had the same issue. The file had been accidentally saved as a Strict XML Open Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make sure you have the right kind of Excel spreadsheet.  I had this same error and realized that I had saved it as a Strict XML Open Spreadsheet which still had the .xlsx extension.

Comment: The right extension is at top of the list of the saving page. +1 Excel Workbook

Comment: I appreciate this answer so much

Comment: Savingi it as `.xls` file in ubuntu fixes my issue when using `read_excel` with `pandas v1.4.1`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read the file, it's better to use `os.path` as follows:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dir = 'path_to_excel_file_directory'
excelFile = os.path.join(dir, 'fileName.xlsx')
pd.read_excel(excelFile)
```

And if the excel file is in the same directory as your script, you can use `inspect` to automatically detect the directory it's in:

```
scriptName = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
excelFile = os.path.join(dir, 'fileName.xlsx')
pd.read_excel(excelFile)
```

One final note: the part

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

is not related to the question.

Comment: which lines gives exactly what error? Can you add some of your data in the question?

Comment: pd.read_excel(excelFile) is still causing the error. I mentioned in the question i had tried a direct path but i just did pd.read_excel("C:\\....\\my_spread_sheet") and got the same error i have added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution: create a brand new file (.xls) with the content of the one that gives you the error. It worked for me.